# How to create scrapy multiple spider or dynamic spider by python script or any other suggestion for do this

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Have tried with scrapy rt but I could not create the spider using API Json web service

Comment: Could you provide more informations about your problem and what you have tried with what results?

Comment: Am very new to scrapy and python, I have tried with scrapy documentation and implemented the basic spider to scrap the website by static, after that tried with scrapy rt for managing the exciting spider...

Comment: Please explain in more details what you mean by _"create scrapy multiple spider or dynamic spider by python script"_

Comment: My requirement is creating the multiple spider for multiple website URL dynamically  and from web I need to input to scrapy (start URL, spider name , spider logics and User credentials etc)

Comment: Plz adjust me with good solution..thanks for responding my questions